# How do you deduce a sample size from the mean and standard deviation here?

Tags: normal-distribution

**How did they deduce to use samples starting from 1000 to 8000 on the y-axis?**

Q:  A Gaussian distribution whose **mean is 100** and whose **standard deviation is 10** is used
to generate **N random samples.** The samples are then used to estimate the mean, µ,
and variance, S, of the Gaussian using the formulae below.

$$ \mu = \frac{1}{N} \sum^{N}_{i=1}x_i$$
$$S = \frac{1}{N} \sum^{N}_{i=1}(x_i - \mu)^2$$

(i) **Use a series of sketches to show how the distribution of the mean estimate
changes as the value of N increases.**
[Sketches provided on Answer sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtJjk.png)

**Explanation from the answer for the Sketches provided:**
Plots above are for sample sizes of 2, 5, 10 and 100. The sketches of the histograms should be of Gaussian shape where the mean is at 100. The spread decreases as sample size increases. When the spread is narrower, the peak should be higher.

**How did they get the y-axis values (1000...8000) on the Sketches just by using the mean and S.D here?**
Are we supposed to calculate the probability using the P.D.F function first after plucking in the mean & S.D then use $\mu = N*probability$ to deduce the values on the y-axis? If so, then I tried that but didn't get the values on the y-axis... I must be confusing something here.

Answer (score 0):

For a fixed sample size (say, $N=10$), you can simulate a data set of size $N$ to get one instance of the sample mean. You can repeat this simulation $M$ times to get many instances of the sample mean, and then build a histogram from these $M$ numbers. This is the histogram displayed in the picture. The y-axis of this histogram will depend on the value of $M$ which seems not to have been specified. (When $M$ is larger, the values on the y-axis will be larger.) In this instance, I think the intent is only to demonstrate how the shape of the histogram changes as $N$ changes; the y-axis is not important (as long as the same $M$ is used for the 4 plots).

Comment: Actually, how do you know the sample size of the first sketch is 2? Also, does that mean I can simply pluck in whatever data I want on the y-axis (Like maybe say 0, 1, ,2, all the way to 8)?